# elasticdump import index setting not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am able to export index setting using below command

```
elasticdump --input=http://localhost:9200/tempIndex --output=/Users/Desktop/indexFile --type=settings
```

but when i tried to import the same setting it is not updating the index setting

The command i used for import is :

```
elasticdump --input=/Users/Desktop/indexFile --output=http://localhost:9200/tempIndex --type=settings
```

output of command :

```
 07:06:33 GMT | starting dump
 07:06:33 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
 07:06:34 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
 07:06:34 GMT | got 0 objects from source file (offset: 1)
 07:06:34 GMT | Total Writes: 0
 07:06:34 GMT | dump complete
```

Below is the settings of my index exported using elasticdump **settings** option

```
{
    "tempIndex":{
        "settings":{
            "index":{
                "mapping":{
                    "nested_fields":{
                        "limit":"2000"
                    },
                    "total_fields":{
                        "limit":"2000"
                    }
                },
                "analysis":{
                    "normalizer":{
                        "lowercase_normalizer":{
                            "filter":[
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type":"custom",
                            "char_filter":[

                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards":"5",
                "number_of_replicas":"1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings can only be added on index creation. So the index must not exist when running this command. You can short-circuit by supplying the appropriate URL, but it still would fail due to the fact that you are trying to update non-dynamic settings.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.number_of_shards]] for open indices [[source_index/_OdHe-IVQBemJ3YYka_9hg]]"
        }],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Can't update non dynamic settings [[ index.number_of_shards]] for open indices [[source_index/_OdHe-IVQBemJ3YYka_9hg]]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

You can do

```
# passing in _settings path will change operation from insert to update
elasticdump --input=/Users/Desktop/indexFile --output=http://localhost:9200/tempIndex/_settings --type=settings
```

reference:https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/issues/549#issuecomment-501223008

Comment: According to your link, running the command you give was only useful to get elasticdump to show you the error message about "you can't update settings, only on index creation". So "You can do [this]" is true, but it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that elasticdump is hiding an error from elasticsearch here. If the index **tempIndex** already exists, then you cannot update the `number_of_shards` and `analysis` settings. These settings are not dynamic. Try running :

```
POST /tempIndex/_settings
{
    "tempIndex":{
        "settings":{
            "index":{
                "mapping":{
                    "nested_fields":{
                        "limit":"2000"
                    },
                    "total_fields":{
                        "limit":"2000"
                    }
                },
                "analysis":{
                    "normalizer":{
                        "lowercase_normalizer":{
                            "filter":[
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type":"custom",
                            "char_filter":[

                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards":"5",
                "number_of_replicas":"1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You are likely to get an error from elasticsearch. Since the request is invalid, no settings will be updated.

You can either remove the index `tempIndex` if that is possible or remove the settings that are not dynamic from **indexFile**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am not trying to update the index which is already present.I want to create the new index and update setting as mention above.
Can you please suggest if i am missing something

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch and elasticdump are you using ? If you are using elasticsearch 7, I think you need elasticdump v6.0.1 at least.

Comment: I am using elasticsearch  6 and elasticdump@6.0.0